# Is it possible to edit/update a nested resource without going through the parent class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Can I update my nested resource without going through the parent class?

I put this in the routes

```
    put 'ratings/:id' => 'ratings#update', :as => 'update_ratings'
```

and I put an exception for [:edit, :update] in the nested  resource route

My controller

```
def update/edit
 @rating = Rating.find(params[:id])
  ...
 end
```

My edit view:

```
 <%= form_for(@rating, :url => update_ratings_path(@rating)) do |f| %>
```

What happens is the server log says the put request happens, but no attributes are updated.  The page then redirects to the show action, when it should go to parent class index page.

The log:

Started PUT "/ratings/21" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-09-25 19:31:18 -0700
  Processing by RatingsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"g4TkuG1xK8W96VSKdl3ZwedrqIXmcg9CDt6y8IqaFh0=", "rating"=>{"environ"=>"8"}, "commit"=>"Update Rating", "id"=>"21"}
  Rating Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `ratings`.* FROM `ratings` WHERE `ratings`.`id` = 21 LIMIT 1
Rendered ratings/show.html.erb within layouts/application (9.8ms)
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
Completed 200 OK in 151ms (Views: 143.4ms | ActiveRecord: 4.8ms)

Comment: can you provide us with logs please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From experience I can say that using a nested resource controller for an unnested action often becomes unmanageable in the long run. So be sure it's not easier to add a second controller. After all, a controller is just an interface to a resource. It's not a problem to have two interfaces to the same resource.

Your log shows "Processing by RatingsController#show", so it never reaches the #update action; instead it comes into #show.

The most probable cause I can think of is that you have a (named) route on a higher line in routes.rb to the ratings#show action, without a :via => 'get'.

Comment: You are correct.  I added :via => 'get' for the show route.  What do you mean by it is unmanageable to to use this practice?

Comment: Well, often you use different before filters, different checks, etc. for (the same) resources that are nested differently. Especially authentication and authorization are often different.

Also if you add new functionality, you always have to take into account that some actions in some controller may be nested differently than other actions in that controller.

In the end (20% of the time/money spent on a typical software project is initial development; 80% is maintenance) it just becomes a mess.

If you ask me, there is no reason to keep the actions in one controller.

Comment: I usually make a RatingsController for the unnested actions and a (for example; depending on your context) ArticleRatingsController for the nested actions.